# List all values from left table

Tags: mysql, join

I have to tables, T1 and T2.

**Tbl1**

```
Name   
A          
B
C
D
E
F
```

**Tbl2**

```
Name   Status
A       0
B       4
C       1
D       4
```

Now i want to show all records from Tbl1 according to Tbl2 except those records who has status 4. The table should look like:

A
C
E
F

```
My query returns only result which are identical and don't have status 4:

SELECT Tbl1.Name, Tbl2.Name
LEFT JOIN Tbl1 ON Tbl2.Name = T1.Name
WHERE Status != 4
```

Comment: So, what do you expect to have and what does the query give you? Because it seems like this is what you are asking for.

Comment: Replace WHERE with AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to also find non-joining rows:

```
SELECT Tbl1.Name
FROM Tbl1
LEFT JOIN Tbl2 ON Tbl2.Name = T1.Name
WHERE Status != 4
OR Status IS NULL
```

Testing for `Status IS NULL` is required because `Status != 4` is not true for all rows where there isn't a join, because all columns are `null` in this case and `null` is neither equal nor not equal to any value.

Also your query was a bit messed up, so I fixed that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.name
FROM Tbl1 A, Tbl2 B
WHERE A.name=B.name AND B.status!=4
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is same as my query. In this case A and C, but not E and F. B and D are eliminated because of their status 4 which is correct, also A and C are printed out and this is also correct but E and F are missing. They don't have assigned status in second table but they also should be printed out together with A and C.